# How can i move the img inside div without accesing all the img in the page?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have a problem fixing a column,the img's inside will not follow the other divs.

I can align img only if i **CSS** all the **img** in the page.

Like this : **img { exemple };**

I put all the img in a div with a class and it wont move.

I am editing wordpress theme.Hope you can help me somehow. Thank You !

```
.poza{
  text-align:center;
  width:100%;
  display:block;
  margin:auto;
  }
```

Here is the exemple : https://jsfiddle.net/azfwuzad/20/

Comment: What do you want to do? Center all the images within their sections?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to target the img in the class .poza only, and you can do it like this

```
.poza > img {
  width:80%;
  display:block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

That's all I needed to add and now your images nested within the .poza class are centered. Hope this helps.

Comment: My pleasure! Glad I could help